# Self hosted WCF (Rest) allows only POST method

Tags: c#, wcf, http, hosting

My WCF service is self hosted, I'm using `WebServiceHost` for hosting using the following code:

**WcfGatewayDatas.cs**

```
 public WcfGatewayDatas()
 {
     Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1478/");
     this.Host = new WebServiceHost(this, baseAddress);
     this.host.open();
 }
```

My base interface looks like this (don't worry about the new):

**IWcfGatewayDatas.cs**

```
 [ServiceContract]
        public interface IWcfGatewayDatas : IExposeDatas
        {
            [WebGet(/*Method="GET", */UriTemplate = "Alarms/Last")]
            [OperationContract]
            new JaguarEvitech.AgentService.SpyAlarm GetLastAlarm();
        }
```

And my config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Wcf">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WcfBinding"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MilestonePlugin.Background.ExposeDatas.WcfGatewayDatas">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="Wcf" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MilestonePlugin.Background.ExposeDatas.IWcfGatewayDatas" address="GatewayJaguar"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When the service is launched I try to go to the url (http://localhost:1478/GatewayJaguar/Alarms/Last) using my web browser and I always have the same error : Method not allowed. The only one allowed one is post (whatever I write in my interface WebGet or WebInvoke). Did I miss something?

EDIT: Even when my url does not match with a WCF function, I have this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. The problem was a bad url request. I wanted to request http://localhost:1478/GatewayJaguar/Alarms/Last but my program was listening on http://localhost:1478/Gatewayjaguar/GatewayJaguar/Alarms/Last. I changed my uri and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

WCF defaults to only using HTTP Post. This link explains how to choose to use HTTP Get  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628610(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I already set WebGet to my function in order to do GET requests. I already added the WebGetAttribute to my function

Comment: You could try [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Alarms/Last")] where there is a "/" before Alarms